# Pandas Dataframe add values interating over columns with jumping values ahead

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a list called `_splitScenario`. I am trying to get the values of this list into a nice data frame. I have a data frame called `SummitVaRProd` . This dataframes has 545 columns. 45 trade attributes and then 500 scenario dates. I want to add scenario values from the list to scenario dates in the dataframe.

In the below loop:

```
        for j, val in enumerate(_splitScenario):
            for ColIdx, ColVal in enumerate(SummitVaRProd.columns):
                SummitVaRProd.at[j,ColVal] = COBDate
                SummitVaRProd.at[j,ColVal] = _splitScenario[j]
```

Now how can I jump to ColVal on 46th column?

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I can use `SummitVaRProd.iloc[j][j+46]`